# adding comment class view

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

Basically I want to create a comment model section like youtube, Instagram, in which we can add comment/body in a detailed view of a post or video, and username which will be posted automatically from request.

`models.py`

```
class Comment(models.Model):
  post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
  name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comment_by')
  email = models.EmailField()
  body = models.TextField(help_text='Add a comment')
  created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
  active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

  class Meta:
    ordering = ('created',)

  def __str__(self):
    return f'Comment by {self.name} on {self.post}'
```

`forms.py`

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Comment
    fields = ['email', 'body']
```

`views.py`

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
  model = Post  

  # display comments and comment_form
  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    qs = Comment.objects.filter(post=self.kwargs.get('pk'), active=True)
    context['comments'] = qs.order_by('-created', '-updated')
    context['comment_form'] = CommentForm() # adding empty form
    return context

class CommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
  model = Comment
  form_class = CommentForm
  template_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'
  success_url = reverse_lazy('post-detail')
  new_comment = None

  def form_valid(self, form):
    post = self.get_object()
    form.instance.post = post
    form.instance.name = self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

I have post and comment models. I want to add a comment form in the post detail view. I'm able to add empty form but unable to post/add comments. When I submit the form with data in it, it shows this error: `This page isn’t working. If the problem continues, contact the site owner. HTTP ERROR 405` PostDetailView works fine but doesn't know how to get working CommentCreateView in correct way. I've just started with class-based views. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to point the `action="{% url 'create_comment %}"` for the comment form to the correct view.

But replacing `{% url 'create_comment %}` with the URL path that points to the `CommentCreateView` view.

example: **template.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'create_comment %}" method="POST">

{% csrf_token %}

{{ comment_form }}

</form>
```

Comment: the problem isn't that I'm unable to link the form to a template. But the problem is that comment isn't being created.

Answer (score 0):

Have you solved your issue? I had the same problem and I solved by doing `form.save()` inside the `form_valid` method.